# Django bulk update with history deletion

Tags: python, django, performance, orm

I'm trying to optimize my Django backend performance. I have a model User that I track with Django Simple History (https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I want to be able to bulk update my User model and then remove this from history. For an individual User, this would look like this:

```
u = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
u.name = "new name"
u.save()
u.history.first().delete() # I don't want to track this change.
```

Performance-wise, which is better?

Option 1:

```
users = User.objects.filter(needs_updating=True)
for user in users:
    user.name = "New name"
    user.save()
    user.history.first().delete()
```

Option 2:

```
User.objects.filter(needs_updating=True).update(name="new name")
User.history.filter(name="new name").delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #2 for all n where n = the number of users that need updating and assuming that the `needs_updating` and `name` fields are flagged with `db_index` or are otherwise indexed in the database (assuming that you have tested it and it works).

By my count:  Option #1 will do 1 + 2*n queries against the database while while Option #2 always does 2 queries against the database.